# Problem with interaction of enumitem and ocgx packages

Tags: enumitem, ocgx

I am trying to create a simple document that contains questions with their respective answers "hidden" behind a mouse click. The problem is when I try to implement this with a list with labels other than default (via enumitem). My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{\bf Example}[section]
\newenvironment{mysolution}{\begin{ocg}{OCG\theex\theenumi}{ocg\theex\theenumi}{0}\leavevmode\marginpar{SOLUTION}}{\end{ocg}\hfill\switchocg{ocg\theex\theenumi}{$\Box$}}
\begin{document}
\section{Math}
\begin{ex}
A math question
\begin{enumerate}
\item
What is $1+1$?
\begin{mysolution}
$1+1=2$
\end{mysolution}
\end{enumerate}
\end{ex}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have `[label=\bfseries(\alph*)]` as an argument for enumerate, but this causes an issue as `\theenumi` renames to `{\theenumi}` (which you can see in the PDF) and `ocgx` cannot read this; this results in a string of errors. This only seems to be an issue with the `enumitem` package as it works with alpha labels no problem, but I can't get them bolded. Any suggestions as to what I should try?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment option `[label=\bfseries(\alph*)]` redefines `\theenumi` from its original meaning `\number\c@enumi` to `\protect \bfseries  (\alph {enumi})`, which is no more expandable because it introduces a formatting instruction (`\bfseries`).

However, the `ocg` environment's name and reference arguments must be expandable. The name is used in the PDF file and appears in the PDF viewer's "Layers" navigation tab, while the reference is internally used for identifying the OCG during the LaTeX run.

In order to ensure its expandability in the `ocg` arguments, we strip the formatting from the enumeration item counter by using `(\alph{enumi})` instead of `\theenumi`. Furthermore, a checkmark is added to the example to be shown when the solution is unveiled. For this, an `ocmd` environment (pkg `ocgx2`) is used in the `\switchocg` link text argument.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{\bf Example}[section]
\newenvironment{mysolution}{%
  \begin{ocg}{Example \theex\ (\alph{enumi})}{ocg\theex.\alph{enumi}}{off}
  \marginpar{SOLUTION}%
}{%
  \end{ocg}\hfill%
  \switchocg{ocg\theex.\alph{enumi}}{%
    \begin{ocmd}{\AllOn{ocg\theex.\alph{enumi}}}
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\large\checkmark}
    \end{ocmd}$\Box$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Math}
\begin{ex}
A math question
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries(\alph*)]
\item
What is $1+1$?
\begin{mysolution}
$1+1=2$
\end{mysolution}
\end{enumerate}
\end{ex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!